# Positive definiteness of difference of inverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ symmetric and positive definite matrices.

If $A \prec B$, then is it true that $B^{-1} \prec A^{-1}$?

Here, $A \prec B$ means that $B-A$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For ease of notation I'll use $\ge$ instead of $\succeq$ and so on.

**Lemma 1:** $A \le B \Rightarrow C^T A C \le C^T B C$ for any conformable matrix $C.$

*Proof.* We have $x^TC^T(B-A)C x = (Cx)^T(B-A)C x \ge 0$ for any conformable vector $x$ so that $C^T(B-A)C \ge 0.$

**Lemma 2:** $I \preceq B \Rightarrow$ $B$ is invertible and $B^{-1} \preceq I.$

*Proof.*

- Since $B$ is symmetric we can find an orthogonal matrix $G$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $B=GDG^T.$ Hence $I = G^T I G \le G^T B G = D.$ Thus all eigenvalues of $B$ are $\ge 1 >0,$ hence $B$ is invertible.
- Now write $B^{-1} = B^{-1/2}IB^{-1/2} \le B^{-1/2}BB^{-1/2} = I,$ where $B^\alpha := GD^{\alpha}G^T.$

**Proposition:** $0 < A \le B \Rightarrow$ $B$ invertible and $B^{-1} \le A^{-1}.$

*Proof.*
\begin{align*}
A\le B &\Rightarrow B-A \ge 0 \\
       &\Rightarrow A^{-1/2}(B-A)A^{-1/2} \ge 0\\
       &\Rightarrow A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} \ge I\\
       &\Rightarrow A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{1/2} \le I,\\
\end{align*}
hence
\begin{align*}
B^{-1} &= A^{-1/2}A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{1/2}A^{-1/2}\\
       &\le A^{-1/2}IA^{-1/2}\\
       &= A^{-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Should the last steps be simply $B^{-1}=A^{-1/2}(A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{1/2})A^{-1/2}\leq A^{-1/2}IA^{-1/2}=A^{-1}$?

Comment: @Knightgu yes that's correct, thanks for noticing!

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks a lot for this very nice answer @Epiousios.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Try proving that if $A$ is positive definite and $B-A$ is non-negative definite, then $\det(B-\lambda A)=0$ has all its roots $\lambda\ge 1$ and conversely if $\lambda\ge1$, then $B-A$ is non-negative definite. (it's an exercise from a book by the way)

Then, $\det(A^{-1}-\mu B^{-1})=0$

$\Rightarrow \det B\det(A^{-1}-\mu B^{-1})\det A\ge0$ $\quad($ as $A$ and $B$ are both p.d., $\det A,\det B>0)$

$\Rightarrow \det(B-\mu A)=0$

So the roots of $\det(A^{-1}-\mu B^{-1})=0$ are the same as the roots of $\det(B-\mu A)=0$.

As $B-A$ is n.n.d. we have $\mu\ge1$, which in turn makes $A^{-1}-B^{-1}$ n.n.d. (by the claim above)

Comment: exercise from what book?

Comment: @becko *Linear Statistical Inference and it's Applications* by C.R. Rao (not a linear algebra book).

Comment: I had asked a question on the proof of the claim made here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2671111/321264