# Show for two positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, if $A \succeq B$ then $B^{-1} \succeq A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Problem: Show for two positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, if $A \succeq B$ then $B^{-1} \succeq A^{-1}$

Definition: $A \succeq B$ if $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.

I've been trying to use the adjunct matrices since $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{det(A)}adj(A)$ so from the $\frac{1}{det(A)}$ it seems sort of obvious that if $A \succeq B$ then $B^{-1} \succeq A^{-1}$. However, I have no idea beyond this how to use the positive definite nature of $A$ and $B$ or definition of $A \succeq B$ to prove the statement. All I know is that if a matrix $A$ is positive definite then so is $A^{-1}$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3251991/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2402563/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom I've been looking for this question for ages, thank you!