# PSD Matrix Inequality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Is it true that for any two matrices $A \preceq B \iff C^T A C \preceq C^T B C$ for any conformable matrix $C$?

[This related question proves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402563/positive-definiteness-of-difference-of-inverse-matrices/3018669#comment8424337_3018669)
($\Rightarrow$) We have $x^TC^T(B-A)C x = (Cx)^T(B-A)C x \ge 0$ for any conformable vector $x$ so that $C^T(B-A)C \ge 0.$

What about the other direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "any conformable matrix"? If you're allowed to have C=I (the identity matrix) then the answer is yes (trivially). On the other hand if you restrict to C = 0 (the zero matrix) the answer is no (trivially).

Comment: Any non-trivial matrix (different from zero and identity) such that the dimension of the matrix multiplication agree

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformable_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse is clearly false. Consider $C=0$ for instance.

For another counterexample we have $\pmatrix{1&0}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}\pmatrix{1\\ 0}\succeq0$ but $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}$ is indefinite.