# Suppose that $\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}$ is positive definite. What can we say about $\left( \mathbf{B}^{-1} - \mathbf{A}^{-1} \right)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

In a physical problem related to minimum dissipation, it can be proven from physical considerations that $\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}$ is positive definite.
According to the definition, we have
$$
\forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}, \quad
\mathbf{x}^\top \left( \mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B} \right) \mathbf{x} > 0 \, .
$$

> Both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are invertible and are themselves
> also symmetric positive definite. In addition, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are positive.

To be able to proceed with a mathematical proof, I was wondering whether this imply that $\left( \mathbf{B}^{-1} - \mathbf{A}^{-1} \right)^{-1}$ is positive definite?

Already for diagonal matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, it can be shown readily that this is the case indeed.

Can we say anything about the positive definiteness of $\left( \mathbf{B}^{-1} - \mathbf{A}^{-1} \right)^{-1}$ in the general situation of interest?

Comment: I'm a little confused because you say the matrices have to have nonzero entries, but then give diagonal matrices as an example.

Comment: From what's given, I can't see a reason why $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ should be invertible. One example can be $\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{B} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks for the comment. It should be $\mathrm{R}^+$.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei Both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are invertible. This has now been mentioned in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2402563/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have
$$
A(A - B)^{-1}B = \left(B^{-1}(A - B)A^{-1}\right)^{-1} = \left(B^{-1} - A^{-1}\right)^{-1},
$$
which proves that $B^{-1} - A^{-1}$ is invertible (it is not obvious) and its inverse equals $A(A - B)^{-1}B$. This is the matrix version of $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a}} = \frac{ab}{a - b}$. Now, let us write $C = A - B$, which is positive definite symmetric (thus $C^{-1}$ is too). And we have,
$$
\left(B^{-1} - A^{-1}\right)^{-1} = A(A - B)^{-1}B = (B + C)C^{-1}B = BC^{-1}B + B.
$$
And for all $x \neq 0$, $x^\top Bx > 0$ and $x^\top BC^{-1}Bx = (Bx)^\top C^{-1}(Bx) > 0$ which proves that $x^\top\left(B^{-1} - A^{-1}\right)^{-1}x > 0$.

Comment: You can get the second equation also immediately via the [matrix inversion lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

Answer (score 4):

In the below, I use the notation $M \succ 0$ to mean that $M$ is positive definite.

First of all, note that $B^{-1} - A^{-1}$ is positive definite. One way to see this is as follows:
$$
A - B \succ 0 \implies\\
B^{-1/2}(A - B)B^{-1/2} \succ 0 \implies\\
B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2} - I \succ 0 \implies\\
I - [B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}]^{-1} \succ 0 \implies\\
I - B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2} \succ 0\implies\\
B^{-1} - A^{-1} \succ 0
$$
From there, it suffices to note that the inverse of a positive definite matrix is itself positive definite. One simple way to see this is to note that a matrix is positive definite iff it is symmetric with positive eigenvalues, but the inverse of a symmetric matrix is symmetric and the inverse of a matrix with positive eigenvalues has positive eigenvalues.

Thus, the fact that $B^{-1} - A^{-1}$ is positive definite implies that $(B^{-1} - A^{-1})^{-1}$ is positive definite.